# apache solr data import from mysql

Tags: solr

i don't know what's wrong but i am not able to get data from solr data import.

**db-data-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="data_so" type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/delance" user="user" password="user"/>
    <document>
    <entity name="table_name" query="select * from table_name" >
    <field name="solr_field_map" column="table_column_name" />
    <field name="name" column="name" />
    </entity>
    <entity dataSource="data_so" name="Jobs" query="select job_title from Jobs">
         <field name="job_title" column="job_title" />
    </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

**schema.xml**

```
   <!-- Jobs Field-->
    <field name="job_title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

**solrconfig.xml**

```
  <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

but when i try to run data import using the following url

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/dataimport?command=full-import
```

i am getting this all the time :-

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">0</int>
</lst>
<lst name="initArgs">
     <lst name="defaults">
         <str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str>
     </lst>
</lst>
    <str name="command">full-import</str>
    <str name="status">idle</str>
    <str name="importResponse"/>
    <lst name="statusMessages">
         <str name="Time Elapsed">0:14:54.768</str>
         <str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str>
         <str name="Total Rows Fetched">0</str>
         <str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
         <str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
         <str name="Full Dump Started">2014-02-26 12:30:42</str>
         <str name="">Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes.</str>
         <str name="Rolledback">2014-02-26 12:30:42</str>
    </lst>
    <str name="WARNING">This response format is experimental.  It is likely to change in the future.</str>
</response>
```

any idea what's wrong.

Comment: What's written in the logs? Of your container (Jetty, Tomcat) or on the console?

Comment: Is the job_title a unique field in your Solr Schema? If not, then you might have a duplication exception error when importing your data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to do the following steps in order to make the data-import to work.

1) Include the JDBC connectors for the database that you are using, i.e., MySQL, DB2 etc. Include  the following JAR in your **solrconfig.xml** file under your core.

```
<lib dir="../../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../lib/" regex="db2jcc*\.jar" />
```

The above works for DB2 server.

Also make sure that you have the following requestHandler in your solrconfig.xml file

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
      <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
      </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

2) Make sure the JDBC connection is actual successful with a connection test and also verify that the SELECT query is correct.

3) Edit the data-config.xml in the core that you are using

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource driver="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
    user="username"
    url="jdbc:db2://hostname:50000/DATABASE_NAME"
    password="password"
    autoCommit = "true"/>
        <document name="customers">
            <entity name="customers" query="
                    SELECT id, customer_name as street_addr FROM customers
                " >

                <field column="id"       name="id"/>
                <field column="name"             name="name" />

            </entity>
        </document>
</dataConfig>
```

4) Make sure that you have a unique field in your list of the import fields, otherwise you have to create a uuid by yourself.

5) Use the SOLR UI interace to perform the import via `http://hostname:8983/solr/#/corename/dataimport//dataimport`

SOLR experts, please let me know if I forgot anything.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the URL and check.

```
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/delance"
```

It's a good practice to provide URL "jdbc:mysql://IP:PORT/database"

Comment: Now i get -> Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.

Comment: I guess you need to modify your query as well. Mention the column name instead of `*`